# Css code that seems to optimize,

Tags: css, webflow

I was curious to what this code does.  I found it on a site, and I am wondering if it has anything to with device optimization. It seems to effect the whole page through all devices. Especially the part that says "@media screen and (min-width:992px)".

```
<style>

html  {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.w-container {
  max-width: 100%; 
}

.w-container .w-row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
} 

.w-row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.w-row .w-row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.w-col .w-col, .w-col {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.pad-row .w-col {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.pad-row.w-row, .pad-row .w-row {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

/*---------------------------------*/

.slider-outer {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slider-left, .slider-right {
    display: table-cell; 
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.slider-left {
    text-align: right;
}
.slider-right {
    text-align: left;
}

/*---------------------------------*/

.w-slider-nav-invert>div {
  border: white 3px solid;
  background: black;
}

.w-slider-nav-invert>div.w-active { 
  border: white 3px solid;
  background: white;
}

.w-slider-dot {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

/*---------------------------------*/

.table {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
.t-row {
    display:table-row;
}
.t-cell {
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .t-cell {
      display:table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;
  }
}
</style>
```

I know that this is css, but it seems like clever code to make the page optimizable through all devices. It is in an html embed on this site https://preview.webflow.com/preview/uniqlo-responsive?preview=aacb16f7eb6a5df89780c3f5bbee094d.  You can go in there and double click on an html embed, and the code will be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is known as a **[media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**.

The `min-width: 992px` you see denotes that the CSS inside of it will only trigger of viewports that are at least 992px wide (which is the equivalent of a laptop). You can think of media queries as 'conditional CSS logic' to control how a website looks on different devices.

Note that the media queries pertain to the **browser** width / height, **not** the screen width / height. As such, manually resizing your browser window will trigger media query breakpoints.

In this specific case, `.t-cell { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }` is applied when the viewport is at least `992px` wide. This will make the content display in a tabular format on larger devices, while the content retains `display: block` for mobile devices (allowing it to stack).

Comment: So can you just drop this in any page and it will do that?  I mean the .t-cell seems not to  referring to any class or element that I know of.  Is it a standard html that can be dropped anywhere to make the webpage that much more optimizable as long as you apply display:block?

Comment: What if I was just to drop the below code, is that not the same thing?    <html type="text/css">
  @media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .w-container {
      max-width: 1170px;
    }
  }
</html>

Comment: `.t-cell` refers to an element with the class `t-cell`. For example, `<div class="t-cell"`. It is not a standard class of any framework (that I am aware of), so was likely custom-built by the author of that Fiddle. Media queries can be used on any website, and are supported by any browser that supports CSS3 (meaning that basically any browser released in the last 7 years support media queries -- IE 9 supports CSS3, but IE 8 does not). `display: block` has absolutely no bearing on media queries -- only `@media` does.

Comment: And your line `<html type="text/css"></html>` is not valid markup -- perhaps you meant `<style type="text/css"> @media ... </style>`. Remember, `@media` is a CSS rule, not an HTML one.

Comment: I went on that site again (the link is also in my question), He has no classes that are named t-cell.

Comment: There are two elements on the page with that class: `<div data-w-id="379569ac-4300-002d-6370-6484360aba3e" class="t-cell"></div>` and `<div data-w-id="91668b57-7611-300c-00f8-bb9e4321733b" class="t-cell"></div>`. They're the two square container elements directly under `Limited Edition`.

Comment: I understand it should have had the <style></style> instead of the html.  I was just going by what they said in this https://forum.webflow.com/t/support-for-larger-custom-media-queries-breakpoints/2707/26.           SAY if I did put the right tags, is this similar to the code in the Question on this page?  Also do you do tutoring?